# Create shortcut to Windows 10 Calendar

Tags: windows, shortcuts, calendar, links, file-shortcut

How can I create file shortcut (.lnk) to Windows 10 Calendar?

I mean the popup window which opens after click to time in right corner of Windows 10 taskbar. (There is time and calendar of actual month.)

Answer (score 2):

It is just "win + alt + D"

Comment: I thought this was a random thing to post to an old question, so I had to test it. This works so brilliantly!

Answer (score 1):

This works in Windows 10 Pro 20H2:

1. Press Win+R
2. Type shell:appsfolder
3. Drag the Calendar or any app to desktop. This creates a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar method. We can create a shortcut by dragging and dropping the Calendar on the desktop, then open it and adjust its display size and placement according to your needs.

For example, we can put it in the upper left or upper right corner, so that we can view the time and date, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: this answer seems depreciated on win 1909 (the icon isn't drop-able anymore) https://i.imgur.com/lpoUwnM.png